# Using Windows Role authentication in the App.config with WCF

Tags: wcf, app-config, windows-authentication

I am using a WCF service and a net.tcp endpoint with serviceAuthentication's principal PermissionMode set to UseWindowsGroups.

Currently in the implementation of the service i am using the PrincipalPermission attribute to set the role requirements for each method.

```
        [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
        [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
        public string method1()
```

I am trying to do pretty much the same exact thing, except have the configuration for the role set in the app.config. Is there any way to do this and still be using windows groups authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood well you want to select the role at runtime. This can be done with a [permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.aspx) demand within the WCF operation. E.g.

```
public string method1()
{
    PrincipalPermission p = new PrincipalPermission(null, "Administrators");
    p.Demand();
    ...
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are hosting your WCF service in IIS, it will run in the ASP.NET worker process, which means you can configure authentication and authorization as you would do with ASMX web services:

```
<system.Web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles=".\Administrators"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.Web>
```

Then you will have to disable anonymous access to your endpoint in IIS, and instead enable   **Windows Integrated Authentication**.
In the IIS management console you do that by bringing up the '*Properties*' dialog for your virtual directory. You will then find the security settings in the '*Directory Security*' tab.

Of course, the only communication channel available will be HTTP. Clients will have to provide their Windows identity in the request at the *transport-level* with these settings:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WindowsSecurity">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost/myservice"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WindowsSecurity"
                  contract="IMyService" />
     </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note that if your service endpoint uses **wsHttpBinding** then you will also have to add SSL to your endpoint since that's a requirement enforced by WCF when you using transport-level security.
If you instead go for the **basicHttpBinding**, you are then able to use a *less secure* authentication mode available in WCF called **TransportCredentialOnly**, where SSL is no longer required.

For more detailed information, [here](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0611051) is a good overview of the security infrastructure in WCF.

Comment: Please note that if you want to do this you need to enable ASP.NET compatibility mode in your web.config file. Otherwise it just won't work (and won't throw an error either).

Comment: Note: for this to work, system.web/roleManager/@enabled must be false, or omitted, otherwise the roles will be IIS .Net Roles, and not  Windows groups.

Answer (score 4):

Lars Wilhelmsen has posted a solution for this problem. Have a look at
http://www.larswilhelmsen.com/2008/12/17/configurable-principalpermission-attribute/

Comment: Current URL is https://larsw.wordpress.com/2008/12/17/configurable-principalpermission-attribute/.